# Photoshop: Bend Anchor Points Around A Circle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, lettering

I want to bend some text around a circle. I can just write the text on a path, but I want to keep the side that's not ON the path in a straight line.

For example, look at these chalk letterings.

The top of this one is a straight line, the bottom is curved:

[image: Mixed Dough]

And on this one, the top is curved, and the bottom is straight:

[image: Work Hard]

Here is my text, including the anchor points:

[image]

I want to pull the lower half of the anchor points down around a path (say, a curve for example), like the pics above.

How do I achieve this affect?

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the vector/shape layer and choose `Edit > Transform Path > Warp`. Then move the handles you see on the shape.

Answer (score 2):

If you goto <kbd>Edit > Transform > Warp</kbd> with your text layer selected and then select `Arc Lower` from the dropdown menu this will give you the effect you want. Change the `Bend` value to make the arc more or less severe.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but I'd like to thank you for the introduction to the `<kbd>` html tag. Never knew that existed.